# Add inherited class to already defined type

Tags: c++

I need to use a quite intrusive homemade SmartPointer class. To do so, the class that uses the SmartPointer must inherit from SmartPointer.
I would like to keep my class clean (no inheritance) and introduce an alternate type that inherits from that class.

Concretely, I have this class:

```
class HttpClient
{
};
```

But in one context, I need to use it with my company's SmartPointer (equivalent to shared_ptr). In order to do that, my class would have to be defined the following way:

```
class HttpClient : public SmartPtr
{
}
```

Instead of the HttpClient inheriting from SmartPtr, I would like to do something like this:

```
class HttpClient
{
};

using HttpClientSmartPtr = InheritsFrom<HttpClient, SmartPtr>;
```

I don't think such a thing is possible, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You can inherit from several classes (`class HttpClientSmartPtr: public HttpClient, public SmartPtr {};`).

Comment: Does something like `template <typename ... Ts> struct InheritsFrom : Ts... {};` do the job?

Comment: Why does your smart pointer require you to have classes derive from it?  Is that to mimic the behavior `std::enable_shared_from_this`?

Comment: @Fareanor and Jarod42: You are right, that's what I ended up doing. I created a utility template similar to Jarod42 in order to do that.

Jarod42 Yes, I ended up implementing the same but for only one class.